# Eclipse STS Grails path issue

Tags: eclipse, grails

Sorry Grails noob here.  I am using Eclipse STS for my Grails project.

I get:

```
The container 'Grails Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/me/.grails/2.2.1/projects/myproject/plugin-classes'
```

I check in finder and the dir

```
/Users/me/.grails/2.2.1/projects/myproject
```

exists, but the `plugin-classes` folder does not.

Any ideas?

Comment: `compile` or `run` the app once.

Answer (score 2):

Things like this happen when changes occur outside of the IDE, and it gets out of sync. To do a refresh, right-click on the project node in the project or package explorer on the left and click Grails Tools | Refresh Dependencies. STS will rebuild its classpath information based on the current state of the project.